# Has anyone tried integrating Tox and SCL on Centos6/7?

Tags: python-3.x, centos, redhat, setuptools, tox

I use CENTOS 6/7 for my development and I was wondering if anyone had some success integrating TOX, setuptools and SCL version of python: rh-python34,  rh-python35 and rh-python36? There isn't much info on the web regarding this topic?

Thanks

Comment: In what you want them to integrate? `tox` is just a program — you create `tox.ini` (listing python versions if you need different pythons) and run it; `tox` creates virtual environments with `pip` and `setuptools` and run your commands.

Answer (score 0):

In your `tox.ini` file you should be able to do something like:

```
[testenv:py36]
basepython=
    /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python3.6
```

Which sets the python to use to create the virtualenv.